# What are some good books about the history of philosophy in the 20th century?

Tags: history-of-philosophy, bertrand-russell

I just read "The History of Western Philosophy" and liked it very much. I would like to now read a history that covers the span after Russell wrote the book, from 1940-present. Can anyone recommend a good book that explains the history of thought for this time period? I am looking for a somewhat high level overview so that if I find something I like I can delve deeper in a different book.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I haven't read it myself, but I've heard good things about [Delacampagne](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0801868149).

Comment: It is very good but does demand some familiarity with the broad themes. Definitely recommended if you have already grappled with Russell's *History of Western Philosophy*, though.

Comment: @JosephWeissman I ended up reading this. I found it more difficult to read than "History of Western Philosophy", but after the struggle was worth it. Thanks for the recommendation!

Comment: No kindle... annoying.

Answer (score 6):

There is "[Philosophy in the Twentieth Century](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0394504542)" by [Alfred Ayer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_Jules_Ayer) which is quite good. But it doesn't go beyond the 70's since it was published in 1982.

Answer (score 3):

The best thing on analytic philosophy in the 20th century is Scott Soames's 2 volume "Philosophical Analysis in the 20th century". That will take you through most of the important stuff in contemporary analytic philosophy.