# Which texts might provide a critical introduction or review of contemporary and recent philosophical movements?

Tags: reference-request, history-of-philosophy

I'm intending to read Anthony's Kenny's 4 volume [History of Philosopy](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Philosophy-Modern-World-History-Western/dp/0199546371/ref=ntt_at_ep_dpt_7). I notice though it stops in 1975 which is fair enough I think. You can't have the history of yesterday. However I'm curious to know what of significance would be missing.

I appreciate there are a lot of academic philosophers so a lot must have been going on in 40 plus years. But I'm interested in major philosophical movements that this may well omit. As a point of reference I should imagine that a book written 100 years ago wouldn't reference existentialism which I would consider a fair major thing - though i appreciate that the seeds of this philosophy predates that.

Is there a book (preferably) or online resource that could fill the gap in Anthony Kenny's work e.g. a critical introduction or review of contemporary and recent philosophical movements. To be useful the resource would need to be targetted at the same level i.e. that of the interested amateur.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I appreciate there are a lot of academic philosophers so a lot must have been going on in 40 plus years.

That's quite an understatement.

In terms of major trends, on the continental I would take a look at Badiou, Žižek, and Agamben, and on the analytic side Parfit and Chalmers-- but these are just the first names that come to mind.

**EDIT:** Since the questions has been edited, I thought I would point the OP to my answer [here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/2019/20th-century-history-of-philosophy/2020#2020), which may help.

Comment: I might add Ranciere and Meillassoux to the continentals, but we are just scratching the surface...

Comment: Thanks for the response. I guess as an amateur I was just trying to get a flavour of what I might be missing. I've tried to tighten up the question a little in response to your answer.

Comment: Saul Kripke! \o/